# SUMs by SUMs in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have two tables, one representing securities ownership (where there may be more than one holding in each security) and one representing distributions on each security (where there may be more than one distribution on each). I would like to compute total distribution paid on each security.

Thus, given input like

```
Security ID    shares held
 44                100
 44                100
 45                200
 55                300


Security ID    distribution
 44               0.05
 45               0.06
 55               0.07
 55               0.03
 44               0.05
```

The output should be

```
Security ID    total distribution
 44               20
 45               12
 55               30
```

The problem is, SUM(A.sharecount)*SUM(B.distribution) ends up double counting some of the positions and I get answers that are too big [(80, 12, 60) instead of (20, 12, 30) in the example above].

SQLFiddle with my sample input and failing SQL can be seen at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3caa/3/0

All advice appreciated.

Comment: Given that structure, how can you know which distribution refers to which hold?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari A distribution applies to every position sharing its security ID. In the above, there are two positions in security 44 with 100 shares each, so distributions need to be paid on 200 shares. There are Two distributions on security 44, totaling $0.10 per share, so a total of $20 should be paid on security 44.

Comment: can you show the math to get $20? because `100*0.05 = 5` and `5x2 = $10`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza There are two positions in security 44, each with 100 shares, so total shares = 200. There are two distributions on security 44, totalling $0.10 per share. Final math, 200*.0.10 = $20.

Comment: I guess he mean `200 * 0.10$ = 20$` or `200*(0.05+0.05)`

Comment: @MatteoTassinari $.10 per share distribution * 200 shares = $20. Why are you using $0.20/share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest fix:

```
SELECT
  A.instrumentID,
  SUM(A.sharecount * B.distribution)
FROM
    samplePortfolio A
INNER JOIN
    sampleDistributions B
ON
    A.instrumentID=B.instrumentID
GROUP BY
    A.instrumentID
```

The reason this is a fix is that the join matches *every* row from A with *every* row from B. If you sum across A, then sum across B, then multiply, you double-count for the rows that got duplicated during the join. If you multiply, then sum, you are multiplying rows only with their "partner" rows.

Problems coming from double-counting join results are one of the most common errors I see in SQL, so be on the lookout!

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3caa/14

Comment: Doesn't look right: ID 44 should have 200 shares, not 400

Comment: Fair point... again, a result of the duplication. Since OP's desired output only includes the total distribution, though, I had assumed the other columns were just for debugging purposes... I'll edit.

Comment: I had to make some modifications to get it working in my actual case but the basic approach works and is very quick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works as requested:

```
SELECT
  S.instrumentID,
  S.shares,
  D.distribution,
  S.shares * D.distribution as total
FROM (
  SELECT instrumentID, SUM(sharecount) shares
  FROM samplePortfolio
  GROUP BY instrumentID
) S
JOIN (
  SELECT instrumentID, SUM(distribution) distribution
  FROM sampleDistributions
  GROUP BY instrumentID
) D USING(instrumentID)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3caa/11)

It works by pre-computing the total number of shares and the total distribution in separate subqueries, and then joins them together to make the product, giving the correct value.